# Date Format conversion return "null" in Kohana query builder

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, query-builder, kohana-orm

Am using kohana query builder to change the cancelled Date format but it return as null value.

Query

```
$result = DB::select('log_id',array(DB::expr("DATE_FORMAT('cancelled_date', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')"),'cancelled_date'),'drop_location')
    ->from(TBL_NAME)
    ->where('driver_id','=','15')
    ->execute()->as_array();
```

Comment: What issue are you facing ?

Comment: cancelled_date field return as 'null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quote for "cancelled_date" and its working fine.

```
$result = DB::select('log_id',array(DB::expr("DATE_FORMAT(cancelled_date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p')"),'cancelled_date'),'drop_location')
->from(TBL_NAME)
->where('driver_id','=','15')
->execute()->as_array();
```